# Asp.net Checkbox OnCheckedChanged not fired when JQuery checks check box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, events, checkbox

Thank you for taking the time to read and review my post. I've done a lot of Google searching but have yet to find the answer to my jquery/asp.net question. My issue is I'm trying to replace the standard check box with an on/off image. There is a neat tutorial about doing this [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/better-check-boxes-jquery-css/). My issue is that my asp OnCheckedChanged check box event is not being called when Jquery places a check in the check box.

#### ASP.NET Master Page Scripts that works

```
<link href="~/Styles/jquery.tzCheckbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.tzCheckbox.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/script.js") %>"></script>
```

#### Aspx Page with Checkbox

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="575px">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Edit_CheckBox1_CB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Edit_CheckBox1_CB_Clicked" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

#### JQuery Script called script.js

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.tzCheckbox = function (options) {

    // Default On / Off labels:

    options = $.extend({
        labels: ['ON', 'OFF']
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var originalCheckBox = $(this),
            labels = [];

        // Checking for the data-on / data-off HTML5 data attributes:
        if (originalCheckBox.data('on')) {
            labels[0] = originalCheckBox.data('on');
            labels[1] = originalCheckBox.data('off');
        }
        else labels = options.labels;

        // Creating the new checkbox markup:
        var checkBox = $('<span>', {
            className: 'tzCheckBox ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : ''),
            html: '<span class="tzCBContent">' + labels[this.checked ? 0 : 1] +
                    '</span><span class="tzCBPart"></span>'
        });

        // Inserting the new checkbox, and hiding the original:
        checkBox.insertAfter(originalCheckBox.hide());

        checkBox.click(function () {
            checkBox.toggleClass('checked');

            var isChecked = checkBox.hasClass('checked');

            // Synchronizing the original checkbox:
            originalCheckBox.attr('checked', isChecked);
            checkBox.find('.tzCBContent').html(labels[isChecked ? 0 : 1]);
            if (isChecked) {
               originalCheckBox.attr('checked', isChecked);
            }

        });

        // Listening for changes on the original and affecting the new one:
        originalCheckBox.bind('change', function () {
            checkBox.click();
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

#### CSS file

```
.tzCheckBox{
background:url("../Images/background01.png") no-repeat right bottom;
display:inline-block;
min-width:60px;
height:33px;
white-space:nowrap;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:14px;
}

.tzCheckBox.checked{
background-position:top left;
margin:0 14px 0 0;
}

.tzCheckBox .tzCBContent{
color: white;
line-height: 31px;
padding-right: 38px;
text-align: right;
}

.tzCheckBox.checked .tzCBContent{
text-align:left;
padding:0 0 0 38px;
}

.tzCBPart
{ 
    background:url("../images/background01.png") no-repeat left bottom;
width:14px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-14px;
height:33px;
overflow: hidden;
}

 .tzCheckBox.checked .tzCBPart{
background-position:top right;
left:auto;
right:-14px;
}
```

#### Last Note

Everything works as needed, I just can't seen to get the page to auto post when JQuery checks the check box. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Changes made through javascript will not fire events such as `onclick` or `onchange`.  What you will need to do is fire the event yourself once you change the value of checked.  I am not familiar with the particulars of .net's `OnCheckedChanged`, but let's assume in the html it turns into `onchange` (you will need to verify this through viewing the source).  You would do something like this:

```
originalCheckBox.attr('checked', isChecked);
originalCheckBox.change(); // will call the onchange code
```